# Shapefiles not editable anymore?

Tags: qgis, vector, editing, digitizing

From this morning if I open a qgis project all the shapefiles are not editable anymore. I've tried different projects in both 2.14 and 2.16 qgis versions. Has anyone encountered the same problem?

[image: Here are the capabilities properties of the shapefile]

[image: Here is the "greyed out" toggle editor]

Comment: Have you set a filter on the shapefiles? Or are they on an USB stick?

Comment: nope to both questions

Comment: Do you have admin access to the shapefiles? Could you use the `Save As...` option to resave it as another shapefile and see if that could be edited?

Comment: I think we had some problems on the permission on the server.. but we're still trying to figure out what's happened!

Comment: Maybe two connections to the same file? I.e. an old connection not closed?