# Unable to edit shp files in saved QGIS project

Tags: qgis, editing

Yesterday I was working on a new project in QGIS. I loaded some shp files, edited them with the "edit" option and saved the project in qgs format.

I've opened the same project today and noticed that the "edit" option is greyed out.

Am I missing some option to re-enable editing?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Cristián! Is your problem similar to this recent post? [Shapefiles not editable anymore?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209578/shapefiles-not-editable-anymore)

Comment: Thanks! and nope, if i open a new project and load the same shp files i am able to edit them (which i use as a workaround).

Comment: Could you add which QGIS version and for what platform (Windows, Linux etc) you are using please? I seem to recall this being an issue for an older version of QGIS.

Comment: I'm using QGIS 2.14.4-Essen in Windows 10 (both 64bits version)

Comment: I had an active query on the layer when i saved my project. I removed the query, saved and reopened and the shp was editable again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your layer has a filter set in the Query Builder (properties of the layer), you cannot edit your shapefiles. Check below where this property is located if you're in this case :

[image: query filter]

It might as well be some write rights if the read only box is ticked :

[image]

Comment: Indeed, i removed the active query i had, saved and reopened and the shp was editable again. Thanks!

Comment: Another tip : by using the "changeDataSource" plugin, you can go even quicker to remove the query and not reopening the project. When the "change data source" plugin is active, just click on change vector datasource and remove what's after the .shp (for example |layerid=0|subset="Id" = 0 in //mysrv/Projects/MyShape.shp|layerid=0|subset="Id" = 0)